# jQuery object different when in variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got a problem I cannot get my head around. The following code obviously works:

```
$("#myspan").text("Some sample text");
```

For some reason, when putting my span object in a variable:

```
var myspan = $("#myspan");
```

**None** of these methods will work:

```
myspan.text("Some sample text");
myspan.innerHTML = "Some sample text";
myspan.val("Some sample text");
$(myspan).text("Some sample text");
```

Only the following will work, but of course I do not like this notation:

```
$(myspan.selector).text("Some sample text");
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't just use the myspan.text() function?

Thanks!

Comment: I opened up the console for this page, and typed: var t = jQuery('#question-header');
t.text('OMGooooodNESS');  it worked just fine. My guess is that perhaps somewhere in your code, you are over-writing myspan?

Comment: Try var $myspan = $("#myspan"); and
 $($myspan.selector).text("Some sample text");

Comment: which notation you want to work ? tell\

Comment: Your first method Works-> myspan.text("Some sample text");          Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eE38s/

Comment: Damnit. thank you guys. I put the "var myspan = $("#myspan");" simply in my head section (and also not in a function). I now put this in the $(document).ready()) function and it works. Sorry guys, you did put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine. Here is the workig fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3fGCx/1/

```
myspan.text("Some sample text");
$(myspan).text("Some sample text");
```

These both will just fine. Below will not work.

```
myspan.val("Some sample text");
```

Here you are trying to change the `value` attribute of `span`.

Answer (score -1):

Try
    `$(myspan).html("Some sample text")`

Comment: -1 `myspan` allready is a jquery object and no need to use `html` if it is text.